# preg_match REGEX cleanup, identifying strings based on starting and ending

Tags: php, regex

I need to clean up Google News links in pages dynamicly, and  get actual links of the content.

Google News link looks like this:

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGkF58EwDE7aA742GfVP9aE8azmhg&url=http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/15/us-obama-mlk-idUSTRE80E0PD20120115
```

I want to keep the actual link, everything after ***&url=*** :

```
http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/01/15/us-obama-mlk-idUSTRE80E0PD20120115
```

I NEED to preg_match/preg_replace and eliminate the "non-essential" part of the URL, in essence targeting everything starting with ***http://news.google.com*** and ending with ***&url=*** ?

```
http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNGkF58EwDE7aA742GfVP9aE8azmhg&url=
```

As you can probably tell, I'm no regex expert. :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` with `~http://new\.google\.com.*?&url=~`, replacing with ''.

Or, you could use `preg_match` with `&url=(.*)$` and pull out `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you, you just want to have the part after `&url=`, so this could be solved with a simple regex like `&url=(.*)$`. If there are other GET values after url, you would need `&url=(.*)&`.

I recommend [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/JRvbMTaqky) to try and play with regexes, although it is ruby-based.